# Update react frontend without refreshing the page using React.js state hook

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I was editing my code to **make sure that my update request performs without refreshing the react frontend**. However, it didn't go as planned. Here's my current situation.

This is my "Profile" component page and I made a test post with title "update me".
[image: My Profile component page]

and here's my Profile.jsx. I'm planning to use "setPosts" useState and useEffect to update the frontend without refreshing the page itself. So, I sent "setPosts" function to my **PostContainer** component as prop along with individual post from my **.map** method.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import PostContainer from './PostContainers'

export default function Profile({currentUser}){

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState()

     useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/post/${currentUser.id}`)
        .then((r) =>{
          if(r.ok){
              r.json().then((posts)=>setPosts(posts))
          }
      })
    }, [])
    
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello {currentUser.username}</h1>
            <h3>What's on your mind today?</h3>
            <div className='postWrapper'>
                <h2>Your Posts</h2>
                <div className='postLists'>
                    {posts?.map((post)=>{
                        return <PostContainer setPosts={setPosts} post={post} key={post.id} />
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If I want to update this post, I will have to press that small "Update" button on the card.
When I press the button this will show up.

[image: After pressing the update button]

It contains a form that allows user to update the selected post.
Let's say I updated this post with following contents and press the Update button.

[image: Entering new info]

It throws me an error message that says "posts.map" is not a function in **Profile.js** file.

[image: Error message that says posts.map is not a function]

But, it shows the updated info after I refresh the page itself. **For some reason, it also created extra "work" tag in the tags section.**

[image: After refreshing the page]

Here's my PostContainer.jsx. Whenever my fetch requests are complete, I used setPosts that was from my Profiles.jsx to set a new state for my frontend. However it is not working as I planned it. I'm a beginner and I need help figuring this out.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function PostContainer({setPosts, post}){
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
    const [title, setNewTitle] = useState("");
    const [content, setNewContent] = useState("");
    const [tags, setNewTags] = useState("");
    const userId = post.user_id;

// Send Delete request.
    function handleDelete(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch(`/post/${post.id}`,{
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(post)
        })
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((x)=>setPosts(x), alert("Post Removed"))
    }

    // Pre-filling the textareas with existing info.
    const handleUpdate = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsShown(current => !current)
        // Preload the information using the set states.
        // setTitle, setContent, setTags.
        setNewTitle(post.title);
        setNewContent(post.content);
        setNewTags(post.tags.map((x)=>x.name))
    }

    // Send patch requests
    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const patchedPost = {
            title,
            content,
            userId,
            tags_attributes: tags.split(',').map((el) => { return {name: el} })
        }

        fetch(`/post/${post.id}`, {
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(patchedPost)
        })
        .then((r)=>r.json())
        .then((x) => setPosts(x), alert("Post updated"))
        setIsShown(false)
    }
    
    return(
    <div>
        <div>
        {isShown && (
            <div>
                <form className='update-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Title</label><br/>
                    <textarea type='text' value={title} onChange={(e)=>setNewTitle(e.target.value)}></textarea><br/>
                    <label>Content</label><br/>
                    <textarea type='text' value={content} onChange={(e)=>setNewContent(e.target.value)}></textarea><br/>
                    <label>Tags</label><br/>
                    <textarea type='text' value={tags} onChange={(e)=>setNewTags(e.target.value)}></textarea><br/>
                    <button type='submit'>Update</button>
                    <button onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); setIsShown(false)}}>Cancel</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )}
        </div><br/>
        <div className='postContainer'>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p className="users-posts-content">{post.content}</p>
            <p>Tags: {post.tags.map((x)=> x.name).join(', ')}</p>
            <button onClick={(e)=>handleUpdate(e)}>Update</button> 
            <button onClick={(e)=>handleDelete(e)}>Delete Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    .then((r)=>r.json())
    .then((x) => setPosts(x), alert("Post updated"))
```

Does your API send back all posts, or only the most recent one? If it's the most recent one, it makes sense that posts.map is not a function, since it is only the one post.
You have to find the updated post in posts and replace it with the one returned by your API

```
    let currentPosts = posts
    currentPosts[posts.findIndex(p => p.id === x.id)] = x
    setPosts(currentPosts)
```

Comment: I found out that my API is only sending back single post that was patched. So right now, I'm trying to figure out the way that I can send back all the posts.